# Telegram Bot Not Displaying Messages - Rasa

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

The bot stops displaying its messages after a couple of responses. The other channels (Facebook, Rasa-X) are receiving the responses. It stops half way in the form.

But when I type the reply according to the next question I designed for the form, it seems to work.

It is selectively displaying some messages in the UI, ignoring the others.

[image: Telegram Not Displaying Bot Messages]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found on the [Forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/telegram-not-displaying-bot-messages/28372). As you found out, seems there was something wrong with how your buttons were formatted.

Just posting here in case anyone else runs into it :)